# pull object out of array

Tags: javascript, typescript

Now the result of `files.splice(index, 1)` is an array and I wanted to push the result of `files.splice(index, 1)` to `splicedFiles`  as an object and not an array of object since `splicedFiles` is already an array, so currently my code resulted into a 2 dimensional array which I don't want.

Is there a way that I can push `files.splice(index, 1)` as an object and not as an array of object? so that it would be push as an object to `splicedFiles` and not as an array of objects.

So basically I want to pull out the object first from `files.splice(index, 1)` and then push it to `splicedFiles`.

So currently this is the result, 2 dimension. which is wrong
[image]

#sample files format

```
const arr = [
    {
        "id": 290,
        "size": 50461,
    },
]
```

#ts-code

```
splicedFiles = new Array();
removeFile(files: any, index: number) {
  return this.splicedFiles.push(files.splice(index, 1));
}
```

Comment: We're going to need some more context, starting with, you need to show us what `files` is made up of.

Comment: The same way you'd get the first element from any array, `theArray[0]`, in this case (since files.splice returns an array) `files.splice(index, 1)[0]`

Comment: So basically I want to pull out the object first from files.splice(index, 1) and then push it to splicedFiles.

Comment: So... as @James said, use `[0]`; i.e. `this.splicedFiles.push(files.splice(index, 1)[0]);` Note that `push` returns the new length of the `splicedFiles` array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shift()` ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)) which destructively remove (and return) the first element of an array. So just push the result of shift.

```js
let array = [{ id: 0 }, { id: 1 } ,{ id: 2 }];
let spliced = [];

spliced.push(array.shift());
spliced.push(array.shift());

console.log(array)    // expect id 2
console.log(spliced)  // expect ids 0,1
```

**edit**
To do this at an arbitrary index, use splice, then dereference the resulting array.

```js
let array = [{ id: 0 }, { id: 1 } ,{ id: 2 }];
 let spliced = []
 
 const moveIndexFromTo = (index, fromArray, toArray) => {
   toArray.push(fromArray.splice(index, 1)[0])
 }

moveIndexFromTo(1, array, spliced)

console.log(array);   // expect ids 0,2
console.log(spliced)  // expect id 1
```

Comment: Great answer, except the OP's function takes an index at which to remove the element...